# Django spliting save function on views

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create a simple messaging application where users can send mail to each other .

[image]

I am able to create a message and send it but what if I wanted to save it as a draft?.

```
<form method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.recipient}}
     {{form.subject}}
      {{form.message}}
<input type = "submit" value= "send" class="save" />

</form>

<input type = "submit" value= "draft" class="save"/>
```

My form has a single submit button which is the send button  intended to send the mail . 
If I were to implement a save function which is the draft function . I would have to also add a save button in the form.If I were to do that . How can I uniquely identify in my views.py Which option has the user chosen?

```
@login_required
def Create(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = NewMessageForm()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = NewMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipient = form.cleaned_data['recipient']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            thread = Thread.objects.create(subject=subject,user=request.user)
            recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
            message =     Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=recipient,body=message,thread=thread)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))



    return render(request,'create.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form,'person':person})
```

forms

```
class NewMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipient = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=1)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True,max_length=1)


    class Meta:
       model = Thread 
       fields = ('subject',)
```

model

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
```

Comment: why don't you ajax this operation, with a views that's triggered by an ajax script and saves the draft called once every 10 seconds? (this is just a rough `draft` idea :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the name of each submit input:

```
<form method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.recipient}}
    {{form.subject}}
    {{form.message}}
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="_send" />
    <input type="submit" value="save" name="_save" />
</form>
```

And in the view, check which was hit:

```
if request.POST.get('_save', False):
    # save
elif request.POST.get('_send', False):
    # send
else:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Note: it is not clear to me why you're not using one of the [many django messaging apps](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/).

Comment: i don't know , I'm still a new learner in django and I don't understand how to custom their plugin

Comment: i guess , you must understand their logic before you can edit it

Comment: Here are some pointers to customise external apps: http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app Hope this helps too ;)

Comment: thank you buddy , jpic can I ask you . How could I approach the code of saving it as a draft using my model . I just need an idea

Comment: Just don't set sentmessage if request.POST.get('_save', False)